# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow not called in iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app which has all views in both Landscape and portrait however there are two view controllers which are in strict Portrait.

I used below method and its working well in all devices except iPad.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    NSLog("Function called")
    if isShouldRotate == true{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown

    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Then I came to know about subclassing the UINavigationController however not know how to implement it.

Please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by subclassing the UINavigationController class!

In App Delegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask  {

    var currentViewController: UIViewController? = self.topViewController()
    if currentViewController != nil && currentViewController!.canAutoRotate() {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }



    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}

func topViewController() -> UIViewController? {
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow != nil
    {
        return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController!)
    }
    return nil
}

func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
    if rootViewController == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if rootViewController!.isKindOfClass(UITabBarController) {
        var tabBarController: UITabBarController = (rootViewController as? UITabBarController)!
        return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController)
    }
    else {
        if rootViewController!.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController) {
            var navigationController: UINavigationController = (rootViewController as? UINavigationController)!
            return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        else {
            if (rootViewController!.presentedViewController != nil) {
                var presentedViewController: UIViewController = rootViewController!.presentedViewController!
                return self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(presentedViewController)
            }
            else {
                return rootViewController
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the particular View Controller where you want not to rotate:

```
override func canAutoRotate() -> Bool {
    return false
  }
```

Comment: Please do share your Swift code.  I'm running into the same issue and hoping the fix will work for a custom tab bar controller as well.  Thanks in advance.